# Numpy index filtering changing multiple variables

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, variable-assignment, matrix-indexing

I notice unexpected results when applying index filtering to a numpy array (`b[b < 3] = 0` ). Any variable that has been assigned from or to the variable that is being filtered will have the same filter applied i.e. if `b = a`, `a` will be filtered the same filter as `b`.

I have created a test file to see what variables get affected when index filtering is applied to a variable. I have ran the code below with results given verse what I expected to get.

```py
import numpy as np

class tester1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
        self.b = []
        self.c = []
        self.d = []

    def test1(self):
        self.b = self.a
        self.c = self.b
        self.d = self.c
        d = self.d
        e = d
        d[d < 3] = 0
        print('self.a')
        print(self.a)
        print('self.b')
        print(self.b)
        print('self.c')
        print(self.c)
        print('d')
        print(d)
        print('e')
        print(e)


class tester2(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.d = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
        self.e = []
        self.t = tester1()
        self.t.test1()

    def test2(self):
        self.t.b = self.d
        self.t.c = self.t.b
        self.e = self.t.b
        self.t.b[self.t.b < 3] = 0
        print('self.t.b')
        print(self.t.b)
        print('self.t.c')
        print(self.t.c)
        print('self.d')
        print(self.d)
        print('self.e')
        print(self.e)

    def test3(self):
        print('self.d')
        print(self.d)
        self.e = self.d
        a = np.array([[False, False, False], [False, True, True]])
        f = self.d
        f[a] = 0
        print('self.d')
        print(self.d)
        print('self.e')
        print(self.e)
        print('f')
        print(f)

    def test4(self):
        a = self.t.a
        b = a
        c = b
        c[c > 4] = 2
        print('self.t.a')
        print(self.t.a)
        print('b')
        print(b)
        print('c')
        print(c)
```

The class produced the results on the top and the results I expect are on the bottom.

when I run `t = tester2()`

```
self.a  [[0 0 3] [4 5 6]]  # Actual
self.a  [[1 2 3] [4 5 6]]  # Expected


self.b  [[0 0 3] [4 5 6]]
self.b  [[1 2 3] [4 5 6]]

self.c  [[0 0 3] [4 5 6]]
self.c  [[1 2 3] [4 5 6]]

d   [[0 0 3] [4 5 6]]
d   [[0 0 3] [4 5 6]]

e   [[0 0 3] [4 5 6]]
e   [[1 2 3] [4 5 6]]
```

When I run `t.test2()`

```
self.t.b [[0 0 3] [4 5 6]]  # Actual
self.t.b [[0 0 3] [4 5 6]]  # Expected

self.t.c [[0 0 3] [4 5 6]]
self.t.c [[1 2 3] [4 5 6]]

self.d   [[0 0 3] [4 5 6]]
self.d   [[1 2 3] [4 5 6]]

self.e   [[0 0 3] [4 5 6]]
self.e   [[1 2 3] [4 5 6]]
```

When I run `t.test3()`

```
self.d  [[0 0 3] [4 5 6]]  # Actual
self.d  [[1 2 3] [4 5 6]]  # Expected

self.d  [[0 0 3] [4 0 0]]
self.d  [[1 2 3] [4 5 6]]

self.e  [[0 0 3] [4 0 0]]
self.e  [[1 2 3] [4 5 6]]

f   [[0 0 3] [4 0 0]]
f   [[1 2 3] [4 0 0]]
```

When I run `t.test4()`

```
self.t.a [[0 0 3] [4 2 2]]  # Actual
self.t.a [[1 2 3] [4 5 6]]  # Expected

b    [[0 0 3] [4 2 2]]
b    [[1 2 3] [4 5 6]]

c    [[0 0 3] [4 2 2]]
c    [[1 2 3] [4 2 2]]
```

Comment: When you do e.g. `self.b = self.a` then `self.a` and `self.b` refer to the exact same array. If you want to have independent copies, do `self.b = self.a.copy()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because you assign variables a,b,c and d to the same array. Think of the variables as access to this array. If you apply filtering to this array. Then it will affect all variables as they are pointing to this same array. If you want to seperate array based on this one you can use copy method like arr_b = arr_a.copy() or arr_b = arr_a[:].

Comment: So assigning a,b,c, and d is just assigning the variable to a memory location. while arr_b = arr_a.copy() is creating a new memory location for arr_b? Thanks for Answer.

Comment: Yes exactly all of these assignments point to the same object. It's the same for all mutable objects. There is also one very important issue. Copy method create what is called shallow copy. It is important if you have nested lists. Copy method creates a copy of an object but not elements. If you want to have complete copy of something like nested list you need to use deepcopy().